# Mimicking C++'s std::unordered_map index behavior in D

Tags: hashmap, d, associative-array, lookup

In C++, the index operator for maps will either return a reference to the existing value if the key can be found, or a reference to a new, default-initialized value if one with the given key cannot be found.

In D, an exception is thrown instead when a value with the given key cannot be found, similar to `unordered_map::at` in C++. So if I want to mimic the same behavior (get or initialize to default), I have to do something like

```
// Assume bar is some associative array of type Foo[string]
Foo* value = key in bar;
if (!value) {
    bar[key] = Foo.init;
    value = &bar[key];
}
```

This seems sub-optimal, given that it involves three hashes (two lookups and one insertion). Is there a more efficient or cleaner way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aa.get(key, defaultValue)` to get the value from the AA if `key` exists, or `defaultValue` otherwise. This can save the extra lookup and if you don't really need to insert the default value in the AA, that's all you need, in one lookup.

i.e:

```
Foo value = bar.get(key, Foo.init);
```

Reference: http://dlang.org/hash-map.html